# Determining the value of the trigonometry expression

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin(x) + \cos(x) = 1/2$, what is the value of $\sin^3(x) + \cos^3(x)$ ? I started by cubing my first equation but I was found some difficulty in finding value for $\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Answer (score 1):

To find the value of $\sin x\cos x$, consider
$$\left(\frac 12\right)^2=(\sin x+\cos x)^2=\sin^2x+2\cos x\sin x+\cos^2 x.$$
Here, note that
$$\sin ^2x+\cos^2x=1.$$

Then, use
$$\sin^3x+\cos^3x=(\sin x+\cos x)(\sin^2x-\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You have a system of two equations in two unknowns: $a+b=\dfrac12$ and $a^2+b^2=1$.